# Facebook sessions not working between Flash and PHP

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

We have a Flash site that integrates heavily with Facebook. When users sign up we get them to allow a Facebook app that ties into the site. This is done through the AS3 Facebook API library from Adobe.

When users have done this, they should then be able to sign up, submitting some personal details and so on. The Flash sends this request to our PHP which then checks to see if the user is actually logged into Facebook, and has allowed our app.

The problem we're having is that when a user goes to do this, the PHP facebook library says that the user is not logged in. If we then refresh the page and try signing up again, everything works fine.

I'd imagine it's a cookie thing, but we're really banging our head against a wall here and can't figure out why it's not working.

Cheers,
Mark.

Comment: Solved it in the end. Bascially, got javascript to refresh itself using fb.init() - this resets the cookies and now PHP curl requests will work fine.

Comment: If you solved it, go ahead and post it as an answer and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OAuth (good example [here by chirs coenraets](http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/12/flex-and-tripit-integration-example-with-oauth-authorization/))

Regardless, you may need to use a flash php/js proxy (php i presume since thats what your using) to deal with any crossdomain policy issues.

Comment: Yeah we're using the Graph API. We're using the classes supplied by Facebook for PHP integration, so just not sure at all why they wouldn't work.